# Wordpress to alternate site title colors

Tags: wordpress

I would really like to alternate my Wordpress site title to alternate colors from an array. My only question is, where should I hook into (i.e which file) to modify the text before it's echo'd? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also its up to you. Hell you can declare your array of colors right before the title tag and use a random number generator to select a color.

Answer (score 0):

This could be in your header.php file - simplest imo. But you can really do this anywhere.

```
$myRandomNumber = rand(0, 2);

$array = array(
    0 => "#fff",
    1 => "#000",
    2 => "#00ffff"
);

$color = $array[$myRandomNumber]

<h1 style="color:'$color'">Title Here </h1>
```

You will probably have to play with quotes or wrap with {}. I am not actually using an IDE to help me with my syntax.